# Does accepting Shabbos early absolve a woman from keeping Hilchos Vestos until sunset?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, niddah

One may accept Shabbos early based on the concept of Tosafos Shabbos. See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim, 267:2. If a woman has a **Hilchos Niddah vest** on Friday such as **Yom Hachodesh** & accepts Shabbos early, does she still need to keep the Halachos of her **vest** until sunset or does early Shabbos make it the next day in regards to her vest?

I know there are several questions on **MY** regarding early Shabbos and other Halachos (such as putting on Tefilin) but I don't know whether all cases would have the same answers. Hence the reason for my question.

Comment: What about after Shkiya on Saturday evening when it's still Shabbat but no longer day-Onah? Note as well that a Hefsek Tahara before sunset after Maariv is generally seen as OK at least bedieved (YD 196:1)

Comment: @Earl This is definitely not an answer, but my strong instinct based on hilchos shabbos, davening, etc. when some people are keeping Shabbos or yom tov or fasts and others aren't is that your personally-imposed time of observance does not affect anything else, and would paritcularly not loosen any independent halachas such as T"H. In other words, it is still her vest. Also++

Comment: I tend to agree with you. Maybe someone can source it for us.

Comment: The halacha for a veset would probably be more connected to the physical day than to a "personal day". A veset is meant to anticipate a woman's cycle and should follow the natural end of day.

Comment: We say the Shema again at nacht even though we brought in Shabbos early. So you can see that bringing in early does not convert day into night for Shema at least and I suggest vestaos as well.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok correct regarding Shema. Is that because Shema is a Mitzva from the Torah? If yes are keeping vestos a mitzva from the Torah or M'dirabanan? Mikva is from the Torah but I don't know about the other halachos. Perhaps that would be part of the discussion if someone can source an answer.

Comment: @Earl Good point. Can you clarify what sort of veses this is. Is this a veses kovua or is it because she does not have a fixed veses?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok a veses that is not kavua.

Comment: Vestos go from Sunrise to Sunset each day. They are not related anyway to the halachic status of day. There is a inyan to do the Betikos before candlelighting so that it shouldn't look like a contradiction. However it is not מעכב.

Answer (score 2):

Shabbos is exactly 24 hours according to the Torah (See maseches Moed koton daf 3b-4a)and tosefes shabbos is a very short amount of time a matter of seconds (tos moed koton 4a), but we don't know exactly when it starts and ends so we keep from shekia (sunset) which is the start of bein hashmoshos (the unknown zone) and motzei shabbos ends at tzeis (either night fall or 72 minutes after sunset) that period we keep shabbos as a must.
.  and tosefos 4a "ma".

The source of a  veses spanning 12 daylight hours (i.e split all the day light equally into 12 hours) or night hours is in Niddah 63b היתה למודה להיות רואה מיום עשרים ליום עשרים ומשש שעות לשש שעות הגיע יום עשרים ולא ראתה אסורה לשמש כל שש שעות ראשונות דברי רבי יהודה ורבי יוסי מתיר עד שש שעות וחוששת בשש שעות עברו שש שעות ולא ראתה אסורה לשמש כל היום כולו דברי ר' יהודה ורבי יוסי מתיר מן המנחה ולמעלה: 
אמר רבא הלכה כרבי יהודה - (translation according to rabbi Yehuda whom the halacha follows)
If she was used to discharging blood on day 20 at 6 hours in the day, had day 20 arrived and she has not yet discharged blood she is forbidden to her husband until the 6th hour( when she is expected to discharge blood), If she still hadn't discharged blood after 6 hours she is still forbidden for the remain of the entire day.

Therefore even though miderabbonon we add on to shabbos even more than the necessary from plag hamincha onward on friday as is allowed in halacha, we still can't change the day boundaries with regards to her veses, and a veses of the day is till nightfall (i.e beyond sunset) as we don't know when the next day starts.